# What are the words at the bottom of this codex leaf from the Gospel of Thomas?

Tags: greek, manuscript, gnostic-gospels

This is the last page of the [Nag Hammadi Codex II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nag_Hammadi_Codex_II#/media/File:Nag_Hammadi_coptic.gif) of the Gospel of Thomas:

The last two lines look like (with mixed cases)

π*γα***ςιον

πκαταθωμάς

The second of these is "according to Thomas" in Greek with a pi stuck at the beginning for some weird reason.  But this is a Coptic manuscript, so even though it has Greek script, the language should not be Greek, right?  So maybe I'm reading too much into it.

The line above it is harder to distinguish, and I'm at a loss.  At first I thought it might be the Greek word εὐαγγέλιον (gospel) but that can't be.  Or maybe it's the Coptic word for gospel (whatever that is, I have no idea) instead of the Greek one.  But then why would the next line be in Greek?

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better images at http://www.gnosis.org; the text in question is at http://www.gnosis.org/naghamm/GTh-pages/th_scan/20.jpg

[image: Scan of p114 of the Nag Hammadi Codex II]

This looks like

> ΠΕΥΑΓΓΕΛΙΟΝ
> ΠΚΑΤΑ ΘωΜΑς

or, in standard “lower-case” letters,

> πευαγγελιον
> πκατα θωμας

...which — apart from the π characters — is straightforwardly “The Gospel according to Thomas.” The lines and dots in the image may be diacritics, but they appear to be rather big.

I have no idea why the two π are there. It’s possible, although it seems unlikely, that they are some kind of new-line/paragraph marker.

Comment: Well done!! Great answer.

Comment: Thank you!  The internet is freakin awesome : )